# Maven define resource

Tags: maven, resources

My project pom definition:

```
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>war/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>localeMsg</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

I want the resource output directory to be different then the src output directory 
(for example war/WEB-INF/localeMsg and not war/WEB-INF/classes)

how can i fo that?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [build helper maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Look at the example for *Add more resource directories to your project*.  The key parameter is `<targetPath>` which can be set to the desired location.